# jquery simple animate/rotate of a css background-image inside a div?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, rotation, background-image

I was wondering if anyone could help me out, or point me in the right direction. I'm looking for a snippet of jquery that will automatically change the background image of a div every say 5 seconds or so. My initial bg image is set in css, but i'm not sure how to create the function to make it swap between an array of images?

I have 5 images:

bg-1.jpg, bg-2.jpg, bg-3.jpg, bg-4.jpg, bg-5.jpg.

Currently my div is set to bg-1.jpg.

```
<div id="page_bg"></div>
```

Don't really have any code to show, but hopefully someone can help me out :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick?

```
jQuery( function( $ ) {
    var images = [ "bg-1.jpg", "bg-2.jpg", "bg-3.jpg", "bg-4.jpg", "bg-5.jpg" ];
    var currentImage = 0;

    function changeBackground() {
        $( '#page_bg' ).css( { backgroundImage: 'url(' + images[ ++currentImage ] + ')' } );
        if ( currentImage >= images.length - 1 ) {
            currentImage -= images.length;
        }
    }

    setInterval( changeBackground, 5000 );  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If those are the actual image names, you really wouldn't need an Array.

```
  // cache the element
var $page_bg = $('#page_bg');

setInterval( function() {
    $page_bg.css( 'background-image', function(i,bg) {
       return bg.replace(/\d/, function(str) { return (str % 5) + 1;});
    });
}, 5000);
```

In the `return (str % 5) + 1;` part, the number `5` represents the total number of images. They should be sequentially indexed starting with `1` like yours are.

---

**EDIT:** Or if there will be a number elsewhere in the URL, then do this instead:

```
  // cache the element
var $page_bg = $('#page_bg');

setInterval( function() {
    $page_bg.css( 'background-image', function(i,bg) {
       return bg.replace(/(\d)(\.jpg)/, function(str,p1,p2) { return ((p1 % 5) + 1) + p2;});
    });
}, 5000);
```