# can you add links to a div's changing background image

Tags: javascript, jquery

Wanna clarify, This code is not mine I found it in another topic here:
[jquery simple animate/rotate of a css background-image inside a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933879/jquery-simple-animate-rotate-of-a-css-background-image-inside-a-div)

Basically it makes a div change its CSS background:

```
jQuery("document").ready(function($){ 
  // cache the element
var $contentHeader = $('#contentHeader');

setInterval( function() {
    $contentHeader.css( 'background-image', function(i,bg) {
       return bg.replace(/\d/, function(str) { return (str % 4) + 1;});
    });
}, 5000);

});
```

It's working fine, changing the background images, but i wanna add links to every background, so my question is, is there a way to make it add a link to each background image it changes, like a location.href so every image can link you to a different site

HTML

```
<div id="contentHeader"></div>
```

CSS

```
#contentHeader {
    background: url("/site_theme/img/adds/bg-1.jpg") no-repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 670px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Different approach in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g7ue7zhm/) (with some dummy images and links):
Define arrays for links and images, step through the arrays and wrap the div in an anchor:

```
jQuery("document").ready(function($){ 
  var $contentHeader = $('#contentHeader'),
      links = [ "link1," "link2"],    // add links here
      images = [ "image1", "image2"],  // add images here
      i = 0;

  setInterval(function () {
    $('#contentHeader').css('background-image', 'url(' + images[i] + ')');
    $contentHeader.unwrap("a").wrap("<a href='http://" + links[i] + 
      "' target='_blank'/>");
    i++;
    if (i = images.length) i = 0;
    }, 3000);
});
```

Also possible to adjust this to a two dimensional array to keep images and links together, but just as suggestion.

Comment: This is exactly what I need if only I could get it working, odly enough I can't seem to be able to implement it in the site, even if I copy paste it and replace my old code, when the site loads I wont load your JQuery app, totally new to JQuery any idead why this is happening...

Comment: @Vacilli Not easy to guess, do you get any errors? You set some image and links like in the Fiddle? And did you also adjust the css? Maybe you noticed that I just commented your `background` for `#contentHeader` out as the setting for the color would overwrite the background image (could be easily adjusted). And in case you used the Fiddle js as example, don't forget to have it wrapped in `$("document").ready` for your site as in Fiddle it's not needed.

Comment: Don't know what I did, but its loading the images now, my bad, but the links are dead, they are not working even when I copy paste your exact fiddle example, with your images and your links...the images change and all but they links are not working

Comment: @Vacilli When the img are working now, it sounds like maybe you previously had a typo somewhere.. strange that it doesn't work for you with the fiddle; you have the same amount of images and links in the arrays? Or would it be possible that you set up your current js in a fiddle as it only seems to be a minor issue, but not easy to guess.

Comment: Thx for the help everything works now, but the container disaapeared and everything is scatered floating, guess Ill try to fix it haha but your program its working, no idead why it made the container dissapear, it replaced the div for a "a" so everything, guess thats it...

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
$("document").ready(function($){ 
  // cache the element
    var $contentHeader = $('#contentHeader'),a = $('#contentHeader').parent();

    setInterval( function() {
        $contentHeader.css( 'background-image', function(i,bg) {
           return bg.replace(/\d/, function(str) { return (str % 4) + 1;});
        });
        $(a).attr("href","your favorite href");
    }, 5000);

});
```

HTML

```
<a href="your favorite href"><div id="contentHeader"></div></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you not want to change your HTML, you could do the following:

```
jQuery("document").ready(function($){ 
// cache the element
var $contentHeader = $('#contentHeader');

$contentHeader.click(function() {
    location.href = "http://domain.com";
});

setInterval( function() {
    $contentHeader.css( 'background-image', function(i,bg) {
       return bg.replace(/\d/, function(str) { return (str % 4) + 1;});
    })
    .click(function() {
        location.href = "http://domain.com";
    });
}, 5000);

});
```

If you wanted the link to open a new window, you could replace this...

```
location.href = "http://domain.com";
```

...with this...

```
window.open("http://domain.com");
```

Note that I'm adding a `click` function in 2 places: once on `ready` and once in the `setIntetval` function, ensuring that the image is clickable from the start.

**EDIT**: To alter the URL's, add them into an array and loop through them every time the interval elapses. So place this above `setInterval`:

```
var links = [
"http://domain.com/1",   
"http://domain.com/2",
"http://domain.com/3",
"http://domain.com/4",
"http://domain.com/5",
];

var i = 0;
```

Then replace your click handler as follows:

.click(function() {
        window.open(links[i]);
    });
    i++;

Note that I'm declaring and incrementing the variable `i` as I haven't seen you doing that in your code. I'm assuming it's done elsewhere somewhere controlling the background image iteration.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bxtjozp9/2/

Comment: Thanks the only problem with this is that is giving me the same link for each background, I'm using 4 backgrounds in this rotation and would like to know if it possible to have each background going to a different URL, I cannot modifiy the HTML.

Comment: This is what I need, only problem is that it is opening multiple windows lets say "http://domain.com/1" is google.com it will open one google.com window, "http://domain.com/2" is hotmail, it will open 2 hotmail.com windows, "http://domain.com/3" is youtube it will open 3 youtube.com windows and so on

Comment: not sure what you're doing, but if you open the demo i created, it always only opens one window...

Comment: In Firefox opens multiple windows x_X, the more you use the program the more windows it will create, doing this directly in the fiddle

Comment: This is the option that I need fdor my current needs I cannot alter the HTML code and using the piece of code in my Question above I need to get each background with a link, problem is that this is giving me multiple windows in Firefox, working fine in IE and Chrome, thx for help by the way