# I want to change background image of a div in every 5 second

Tags: jquery, html, slideshow

Hi I'm trying to change the background image of a div in every 5 second and repeat these images .Using simple html like a div with a class and id.

```
 <body>

<div class="background-rep" style="max-width:500px">
  <p>The slides </p>


</div>

<script>
var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
    var i;
    var y =["img_rr_01.jpg" , "img_rr_02.jpg" , "img_rr_03.jpg", "img_rr_04.jpg" ];
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("background-rep");
    for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
       x.style.backgroundImage = url(y[i])";  
    }
    myIndex++;
    if (myIndex > y.length) {myIndex = 1}    
    x.style.backgroundImage = "block";  
    setTimeout(carousel, 9000);    
}
</script>

</body>
```

I try some of the solution from the stackoverflow but they are not working good 
Thanks

Comment: What solution did you try? Can you post that code?

Comment: Where is the image tag?

Comment: So what did you attempt?

Comment: @MattL. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34690104/make-javascript-change-background-image-every-5-seconds here is my attempt

Comment: @yuvrajprogrammer as i say i want to change a background image of a div

Comment: don't know why people are down voting the post? i'm new to stack overflow and don't know the standards to post message ? is it bad for a beginners  to ask a help

Comment: So what is the issue you have with the selected answer?

Comment: We're here to help. Just please edit your question and post the code that YOU used that is giving you issues

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask <-- read that

Comment: Your question lacks details, so we have no clue what your problem is. That is why it is getting down voted. You need to provide us with info so we can help. What are the errors in the console when you add the script?

Comment: Ok i will create a new post with all details

Comment: or edit this one....

Comment: please have a look i edit the post

Comment: Is there a reasy for which you are coding in pure JS you carousel ?
With JQuery will be more robust. I think you can have some answers here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933879/jquery-simple-animate-rotate-of-a-css-background-image-inside-a-div

Comment: Side note:  it's best to use meaningful names for your variable, instead of x, y, etc.  Especially as code gets more complex, it's tough to remember what x and y are.  If they have meaningful names, you don't have to remember and it's easier to debug and maintain the code.

Comment: "With JQuery will be more robust." is not a factual statement.

Comment: i was just wondering why he wants to code in pure JS (for learning for example)...

Comment: @Pierre There could be many reasons, and the fact that you assume that writing the solution in jQuery is better than vanilla JS, is why I down-voted your answer (in addition to not including the code). One reason a developer may choose JS vs jQuery is performance. One could say vanilla JS is more robust than jQuery, but not the other way around :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues here. First of all: getting the element should be

```
var x = document.querySelector('.background-rep');
```

Next, your loop currently results in the last image in the array being set, as well as improper syntax. I think you're looking for:

```
x.style.bacgkroundImage = "url(" + y[myIndex] + ")";
```

You should also get rid of the line `x.style.background = "block"` as that will override the newly set background image.

Also for 5 second intervals, your `SetTimeout` should be 5000, since it is measured in milliseconds:

```
setTimeout(carousel, 5000);
```

Comment: Still not getting anything

Comment: Got solution just got a single problem trying to use this 
.css( { backgroundImage: 'url(' + images[ ++currentImage ] + ')' } )
i want to make important background image css how can i do this

Comment: Just add !important after the url: `.css( { backgroundImage: 'url(' + images[ ++currentImage ] + ') !important' } )`